# Do invariants apply to stateless objects?

Tags: java, stateless, invariants

I'm reading about invariants, and I'm not sure I understood it completely. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_invariant),

> The class invariant constrains the **state** stored in the object.

So, if I got it right, invariants don't apply to stateless objects because there are no constraints. Is that correct? Am I wrong? Am I comparing apples to oranges?

Comment: A stateless object would have only compile time constant fields - so no, there cannot be any invariants. It's methods could have invariants, however.

Comment: Intuitively, no. If you have no state, then you won't be able to apply invariants to the class. What invariants could you make when there is no state to perform conditions against?

Answer (score 1):

Stateless object doesn't have any state. Take an example of say utility class which doesnt have any field or has constant fields like below:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static final int number = 1;   
    private final int count = 1;
}
```

This means that number/count will not change and will remain consistent irrespective of being referred by 'n' number of threads.

While if i take a class with say private field and is being say accessed by setter/getter then it will look like:

```
public class MyInvariantClass {
    private int number;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void incrNumber() {
        this.number++;
    }
    public void setNumber() {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

This class MyInvariantClass, has a state with number field. Think of this object being passed to multiple threads. Some may increment it, some may set it. Does it guarantee that number which we are using never goes out of int range and there by defaulting to negative? So here we fail to maintain invariant of integer when overflow occurs.

Comment: Why do you focus on multithreading? I don't think invariants are specially significant with multiple threads, are they?

Comment: No you are right. But just saying say even when you are calling incrNumber method, then as well you wont guarantee it will overflow and move back to negative number.

Answer (score 0):

The invariant would be something like:

`myBankAccount.Balance >= 0` between calls to any of the object's (`mybankAccount`) methods. The `Balance` variable is a member of the `myBankAccount` object.

If we have a stateless object, i.e. an object without any data members associated with it, then we can't really define an invariant (what would we define it on?).

Answer (score 0):

A stateless class has no instance members, and therefore there is no state to keep valid.

From wikipedia:

> In computer science, an invariant is a condition that can be relied
>   upon to be true during execution of a program, or during some portion
>   of it.

In java, these conditions (invariants) can be programmed into your code in a few ways.  Here are some:

1. using the final keyword
2. using asserts
3. throwing exceptions
4. using mutator methods

For example, take the class Age:

```
public class Age {
    private final int age;

    public Age(int age) {
        // Use exceptions...
        if (age < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age cannot be less than 1");
        }

        // Or use assertions...
        assert age > 0;
        this.age = age;
    }

    // A method can be a invariant as well, because it makes sure
    // member variables cannot be set to an invalid state.
    public Age changeAge(int age) {
        assert age > 1;
        return new Age(age);
    }
}
```

So, the final keyword is a compiler-time invariant because it makes sure the variable is not reassigned.  The exception and assertion in the constructor are runtime invariants because they constrain age and make sure age is greater than 0.  The public method is an invariant as well, because it asserts if it's argument is invalid.

Some languages have the concept of invariants built right in.  On the wikipedia page you linked to, they list D and Eiffel as examples.  What this means is that instead of raising exceptions, asserting and checking conditions, you can define a constraint (invariant) in one place, and the language has support to make sure that the instance variables remain within the constraints you set.  In java, you must do this 'manually'.